# How can I enable caching of HTML and CSS files on an Electron App?

Tags: electron

I want to enable caching of certain or all HTML and CSS files on my Electron App. I've tried adding the following meta tag to my HTML files and it doesn't seem to do much of anything:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="public/private">
```

(** I used "public/private" to indicate I've tried both values separately)

I'm simply wondering if Electron has a built-in method for caching files or if the meta tags should be working. I tried searching for cache documentation on Electron's Website to no avail.

I read somewhere that caching is enabled by default on Electron but it doesn't appear to be working too well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the session module in Main is how to definitively enable it.

> **session.fromPartition(partition[, options])**
>    - partition String
>    - options Object (optional)
>       -cache Boolean - Whether to enable cache.

https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/eed72c35d74947853ed75dd10e85d5ed56c1ce86/docs/api/session.md#sessionfrompartitionpartition-options